# Turn a button to a link with the same exact functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, button, hyperlink

So I have this button:

```
<%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :remote => true %>
```

It calls the create method in the video_votes controller, and also sets params[:type]. I want to turn this button into a link so that is does exactly the same thing. How do I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't a css class for your button that you want to act as link do the trick, instead of ajax remote ? That's what I did : in the user pov,mit the it's a link, but he clicks a button, that submits the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :remote => true
=>
link_to "+1", video_votes_path( video, :type => "up"), :remote => true, :method => :post
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `button_to` to `link_to_remote` with an extra parameter: `:method => :post`, and take out the `remote`.

Uh, leave out the `method` if you want a GET.

Comment: Why take out the remote? Shouldn't it be `link_to` and pass `remote => true` as an option?

Comment: `link_to_remote` is deprecated in favor of `link_to` with `remote => true`